# Limit of the sequence $ x_{n+1}=x_n+\sqrt{a+x_n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a$ be a real number and $x_1>0$.

The sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is recursively given by the relation: $$ x_{n+1}=x_n+\sqrt{a+x_n^2}$$ for any natural number $n$. How to evaluate the limit $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 2^{-n}x_n$ ?

I think we have to consider the two cases $a>0$ and $a<0$ separately. The case $a<0$, I could manage by making the substitution $x_n = -a\cosh y_n$, and the limit came out to be $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

I can't figure out how to deal with the case $a>0$. Any pointers, ideas or solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $a>0,$ you can first let $x_n=\sqrt a\cot{\alpha_n}.$ Then, using recurrence relation we have:

$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a} (\cot \alpha_{n}+\frac{1}{\sin \alpha_n})=\sqrt{a}\cot {\alpha_{n}/2}.$$

Therefore, $\alpha_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha_n}{2}.$ The rest should be clear.